# Get key name from keycode

Tags: command-line, bash, xinput, keycodes

I am writing a shell script that uses `xinput`, and I would like to get a human-readable description of what the user has typed using the keycode from `xinput`.

For example, <kbd>A</kbd> generates 38. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is 37.

How can I get those key names from the codes?

Comment: Start with `man -k keycode`?

Comment: That's close, but as far as I can tell those only return the keyboard mappings which isn't a very good description of what the keys actually are. Also, most of them don't work: `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console`.

Answer (score 2):

If your on Xorg use `xev`: It opens a window that catches all events (incl. keystrokes) and displays the results, e.g.:

```
enter code KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
root 0xc2, subw 0x5400002, time 29136757, (50,54), root:(1311,78),
state 0x1, keycode 38 (keysym 0x41, A), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (41) "A"
XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (41) "A"
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Maybe have a look at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/extra_keyboard_keys for more details.